# javac not found sublime

Tags: java, sublimetext3, build-system

Error: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I'm trying to set up Sublime Text 3 to run Java.

I already set `PATH`, `CLASSPATH` and `JAVA_HOME`. This is what I have in `MyJava.sublime-build`:

```
{
    "cmd":["javac", "$file_name","&&","java","$file_base_name"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "path":"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_102\\bin\\",
    "selector": "source.java",
    "shell":true
}
```

My `PATH` is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin.

`ClassPath` is JAVA_HOME/lib.

`JAVA_HOME` is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102`.

I read many similar questions but none of the suggestions work.

Comment: `jdk1.8.0_102` would be ***really*** old, are you **certain** that is the version you installed?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch
Went ahead and downloaded newest Java version and JDK. Changed code to
{
 "cmd":["javac", "$file_name","&&","java","$file_base_name"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "path":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk-13.0.1\\bin\\",
    "selector": "source.java",
    "shell":true
}
but same error

Comment: Are you sure you're using this build system and not the one that ships with Sublime by default?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)", especially "Spelling, grammar and formatting". SO isn't a message board, instead it's like an online reference book of programming Q&A, where grammar and formatting do matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I had two copies of MyJava accidentally and was not using the right one. The code works :)